# How do I throttle network activity in Linux?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

How do I throttle network activity, system-wide?

Say, I'm running rsync on a large archive with a cron, or a torrent server, or both. It's important that these activities will be running, but they are low-priority: I don't want them to clog the network and interfere with the other, more important tasks. How do I throttle them?

I'll be running these tasks in a separate, dedicated KVM virtual machines on a CentOS host. So I would prefer to throttle network activity system-wide. The guest machines will be CentOS, too, unless anything dictates otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you just set I/O limits on the VM?

Comment: @michael-hampton I haven't figured the possibility.

Comment: For rsync look at the `bwlimit` flag. For Linux commands in general look into `nice` and `ionice`. Also you can throttle bandwith with Linux `tc` although it's a bit tricky to set up.

Comment: @LinuxDevOps - remember that `bwlimit` only applies on a per-file basis, not on the overall rsync stream, so it's only useful for rsync jobs for relatively large files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options you may wish to investigate.

1. Application-specific limters. As mentioned above rsync has bwlimit and most torrent servers have bandwidth limiting functionality. Pro: simple to set up. Con: not dynamic (e.g. if you set the limit to 20Mbps on a 100Mbps connection at most 20 will be used even if no other program is generating traffic.
2. General purpose user-space limter. I only know of trickle http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle Pros: simple to set up and general purpose. Con: not dynamic.
3. Kernel limiter, e.g., HTB http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classful.html#AEN1071 Pros: dynamic bandwidth allocation; extensive prioritization options. Cons: arcane as hell. You also need a classifier:

3a. cgroups with the net_cls classifier. (This is how KVM-based virtualization solutions limit resources). Pro: relatively simple to set up https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html . Cons: need to have a kernel that supports cgs; still need to use the kernel limiter.

3b. Another is iptables with the MARK target. Pros: relatively simple to set up; extensive classification options. Con: still need to use the kernel limiter.

Comment: Looks like I should use HTB on a host rather than guest machine to get the benefits of dynamic bandwidth allocation? This looks like exactly the kind of thing I'm afraid of adding to my system. Also, what's cgs?

Comment: If you are running these services in VMs then yes you should do it on the host. cgs is shorthand for control groups.

Comment: That's a lot of options. Can you point me to specific tutorials that I can read to get started with HTB and iptables with MARK target? I would like to get familiar with these technologies before I migrate the production sites to the server, if at all. Yes, there are going to be old production sites, new experimental sites and hobby projects on different VM's on that server; that's the reason I'm using virtualization. I assume that HTB, being so ancient in internet years, is ubiquitously deployed in all kernels (if not deprecated).

Comment: Can you point me to where could I go to get started with HTB and iptables with MARK target?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Traffic_Control seems like a good intro and http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.html goes into detail.

Answer (score 0):

rsync has an option for throttling it's own bandwidth: `--bwlimit`

Sometimes I will run this in conjuction with `ionice` on the rsync pid, if I want to make sure to throttle both disk I/o and bandwidth.